# How to display error separately on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I clicked on login, but the right side of register the *errors* shows up.

[image]

this is my view

```
<!-- REGISTER AREA LEFT SIDE -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Member Login</h3>
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('login') }}">
        ....
</div>

<!-- REGISTER AREA RIGHT SIDE -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Member Registration</h3>
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('register') }}">
        ....
</div>
```

and this is my controller return

```
return Redirect::back()
    ->withInput()
    ->withErrors($validation);
```

any way to rename the error with `login_error` and `register_error`? how to separate them into two variables, cause it conflict and shows both message on right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields have names in html, and laravel binds the error to their names so that you can display the error for a specific field, so you can wrap the login form error block with something like:

```
@if($errors->first('login_email') || $errors->first('login_password'))
// ...
@endif
```

and the registration form error block with:

```
@if($errors->first('register_email') || $errors->first('register_password') || $errors->first('register_password_bis'))
// ...
@endif
```

This may not be the best solution, but I know it works and it will avoid to use hacks. Plus it does not add too much boilerplate as you do not have a lot of fields there.

Depending on how you built your constructor, you could also [flash a message](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data) in the session in order to tell your view which form you validated:

Login

```
@if (count($errors) > 0 && Session::has('validated_login_form') == true)
// ...
@endif
```

Registration

```
@if (count($errors) > 0 && Session::has('validated_registration_form') == true)
// ...
@endif
```

Another way of doing it would be to look how the `withErrors($validation)` function works in Laravel sources and see if you can reproduce it yourself but naming $errors differently depending on the form you just validated.